# Radius of convergence in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

We have an analytic function $f$ in some open ball $B(0,1)$. Assume radius of convergence of the power series of $f$ at $0$ is 1. Consider the taylor series of $f$ at $1/2$. Then its radius of convergence should $1/2$, since $f$ is only assumed to be defined and converge in $B(0,1)$.

But it feels strange to me, since I heard that if power series at $a_0$ converges at some point $a$ with $|a-a_0| =\epsilon$, then the power series converges in $B(a_0,\epsilon)$. But I am unsure about this now. Because if then the power series at $1/2$ would have radius of convergence of $3/2$.

Can you help me with telling me which concept is wrong?

Comment: The radius of convergence of the Taylor series of $f$ with centre $1/2$ can be any number in $\bigl[\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2}\bigr]$. Consider $f_t(z) = \frac{1}{z-e^{it}}$ for $t \in [0,2\pi]$.

Comment: "Then its radius of convergence should $1/2$, since $f$ is only assumed to be defined and converge in $B(0,1)$." Not true, $f$ might be defined outside of $B(0,1)$ as well. Example: $f(x)=1/(1+x)$

Comment: @DanielFischer So "if power series defined at $a_0$ converges at $a$ with $|a-a_0|=\epsilon$, then the power series converges in $B(a_0,\epsilon)$" is false?

Comment: In your question you have $\lvert a-a_0\rvert = \epsilon$, in the comment you have $<\epsilon$. For $= \epsilon$, we can conclude that the power series converges _at least_ in $B(a_0,\epsilon)$. It may converge in a larger disk.

Comment: @DanielFischer Sorry for making that mistakes. But in the example, since the power series evaluated at $1/2$ converges at $-3/4$ (because it is where the power series at $0$ converges (I guess this is where I made the mistake)), so it should have radius of convergence at least $5/4$. But then it seems that the power series at $0$ will also converge in $B(1/2,5/4)$, which should not be right. So I just wonder if I have made a mistake.

Comment: The mistake is that you mix up the power series with centre $0$ and the power series with centre $\frac{1}{2}$. The power series with centre $0$ converges at $-\frac{3}{4}$. The power series with centre $\frac{1}{2}$ may or may not converge at $-\frac{3}{4}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks I think I got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The power series around $z_0$ converges in the circle that has $z_0$ as center and reaches up to the nearest singularity of the function. If you have a function that converges inside $\lvert z - 0 \rvert < 1$, the nearest singularity (even the only one) could be at $z = -1$, in which case your second series will converge inside $\lvert z - 1/2 \rvert < 3/2$.

"Walking around" singularities like this you can define the *analytic continuation* of the function by overlapping circles in which the series converge.